# Make one simple C# static function a WebAssembly

Tags: c#, webassembly

I have a 20-line string manipulation static C# method that doesn't have a dependency on any IO or any 3rd party lib. In other words, it is self contained.

```
public static string Manipulate (string val) {
    string results;
    // Do string manip stuff to val
    return results;
}
```

I want to use a similar functionality in JavaScript to do what this function does, which might create a difference between the server side and the client side. Alternatively, this can be an Ajax call to maintain the same behaviour on client and server.

WebAssembly is another option, but I didn't find much about C# and WebAssembly and Blazor is too much for what we are looking for.

Given this is an internal app, so browser permissions are not an issue and the browsers used are the evergreen ones.

Is there any tutorial to guide us through compiling a simple C# method to wasm? The requirement is to read one textbox "TextBoxInput" pass the input to the function on change and put the results in another textbox "TextBoxOutput".

Comment: WebAssembly is still nascent.  The tooling isn't quite there yet for production use.

Comment: Maybe, but it will be. It will be a factor to take into account very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this (a WASM compiler for C#) does not exist. Blazor does this by running Mono (which is compiled to WASM) in the browser. And then this Mono runtime executes your .netstandard (C#) assemblies.

If it is only one function and you are worried about different behavior, your best bet is making an Ajax call and run the code on the server side.